# Indices where values in array occur in another array

Tags: python, networkx

i have this array :

```
n=nodes of the graph
a=np.random.choice(n,size=3)
prob=np.zeros((1,n))
```

how can i assign nodes in `a` to `prob` based on the index of the node?
i have this code:

```
for k in a:
    m=nodes.index(k)
    b=np.zeros((1,n))
    b[0][m]=1
here the results

[[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
  0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
[[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
  0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
[[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0.
  0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
```

but for me, i want this result

```
[[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0.
  0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
```

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're resetting `b` on each iteration, you need to initialise `b` before the `for` loop and *then* update `b` in each with the result of `m`. Also note that `b` only needs 1 axis. Let's consider for example the following list of nodes, and an array `a` of nodes which we'll use to lookup the position in `nodes`:

```
nodes = [5,12,6,1,3,9,4,8,2,45]
a = np.array([5, 9, 8, 4])
```

Adapting your approach, you'd have:

```
b=np.zeros(len(nodes))
for k in a:
    m=nodes.index(k)
    b[m]=1

print(b)
# array([1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0.])
```

Note however that this has an unnecessary `O(len(nodes)*len(a))` complexity. A better approach would be to build a lookup table mapping value to positions in `nodes`, and assign to `b` as:

```
d = {v:k for k,v in enumerate(nodes)}

b=np.zeros(len(nodes))
for k in a:
    b[d[k]] = 1

print(b)
#array([1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0.])
```

---

Also, since you're using numpy we could speed up the above using `np.searchsorted` with `np.bincount`:

```
nodes = np.array(nodes)
nodes_s = nodes.argsort()
s = np.searchsorted(nodes[nodes_s],a)
b = np.bincount(nodes_s[s], minlength=len(nodes))

print(b)
# array([1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0])
```

Comment: Wao, wanderfull answe, very usefull, Thank you